# How to use the context of a string as a variable java

Tags: java, string, variables

So I have the following :

```
String string = "camera_icon"
```

and in another place I have:

```
Object camera_icon = new Object();
```

i then refer to it as:

```
do.some.stuff(camera_icon);
```

is there a way that i can type the following:

do.some.stuff(string);

and get it to work.

Comment: [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) is what you want.

Comment: can you explain more @DaftPunk

Comment: thanks didnt see it, my bad

Comment: @DaftPunk is right, also you would have `Map<String,Object>` that holds each object with each name, and get the Object from the map by string name passed :D

Answer (score 0):

You can either use reflection to get the object as long as it is an instance or class variable.

Alternatively you can put your object into a `Map` and look it up in the `Map`:

```
Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();
objects.put(string, new Object());
```

Later

```
Object myObject = objects.get(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection:

```
class Main
{
   YourObject cameraIcon = new YourObject();
   public void someMethod() throws Exception
   {
      Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField("cameraIcon");
      YourObject object = (YourObject)field.get(this);
   }
}
```

As far as I know, you can't get a local variable using reflection:

```
public void someMethod() throws Exception
{
   YourObject cameraIcon = new YourObject();
   // can't get cameraIcon from "cameraIcon" here
}
```